# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : angular.js:14525 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=MyCtrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been trying to make a weather application where I can retrieve data from a database.  I'm receiving two errors that i can't figure out what is causing them.  One error is syntax error: unexpected token :.   The code  is:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

  getForecast($scope.Location.Latitude, $scope.Location.Longitude, false);
  getForecast = function (lat, lng, isretry) {
    var _weather = []
    if (ConnectivityMonitor.isOnline()) {
        WundergroundService.getThreeDayForecast(lat, lng).then(function (r) {
            if (r.success) {
                if (r.data.response.error) {
                    if (!isretry) {
                        // retry in 0.5 seconds if there was an error
                        setTimeout(function () { getForecast(lat, lng, true); }, 5000);
                    }
                    $scope.hasWeather = false;
                }
                else {
                    angular.forEach(r.data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday, function (forecastday) {
                        if (forecastday.period <= 5) {
                            _weather.push(forecastday);
                        }
                    });
                    $scope.weather = _weather;
                    $scope.hasWeather = true;
                }
            }
            function CurrentWeather(lat, lon) {
                http://api.wunderground.com/api/e217707248f71e69/conditions/lat_lon
                x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
                "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

                "response": {  
                    "version": "0.1",
                        "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
                            "features": {
                        "conditions": 1
                    }
                },
```

The error is on the response line.  I'm also getting an error on the angular cdn I'm using.  The like to the cdn is: Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=MyCtrl at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
      <style>
        html {
            align-content: center;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
            font-size: 12pt;
            background-image: url("https://s.w-x.co/lightning_wunder_photo_3.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
      </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/Controller.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.1/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/jszip.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                $("datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);

        fetch.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'Scripts/getData.php'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                // Store response data
                $scope.users = response.data;
            });
        }]);

    </script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.myTxt = "You have not yet clicked submit";
            $scope.myFunc = function () {
                $scope.myTxt = "You clicked submit!";
            }
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController" class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <ion-view title="Home">
            <ion-content class="has-header">
                <!-- Display current location's weather data-->
                <h3>{{city}}</h3>
                <h5><weather-icon icon="current.icon" id="current-icon"></weather-icon> {{current.currently.summary}}</h5>
                <a id="Nearest" src="CurrentWeather()" rel="CurrentWeather"></a>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>

        <ion-view title="Home">
            <ion-content class="has-header">
                <!-- Display Weymouth location's weather data-->
                <h3></h3>
                <h5><ng-model="CurrentWeather()"   weather-icon icon="weymouth.icon" id="weymouth-icon"></ng-model="CurrentWeather()"=weather-icon></h5>
                <a id="Weymouth" src="Weather()" rel="Home"></a>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>

        <div>
            <table>
                <form method="post">
                <tr>
                    <td>

                       <!-- Display records -->
                       <Input type="date"    ng-repeat="user in users"  class="datepicker">{{date.month/date.day/date.year}}</Input>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> 
                      <button type="submit" ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-submit="MyFunc()" onclick="Scripts/getData.php">Get Data</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                </form>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

What is going wrong here?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: in your html you use `ng-controller="MyController"` but in your javascript you use:  `app.controller('Ctrl', ..)` use MyController

Comment: There are many issues here

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I changed it to MyController.  It looks like the error is still.  I'm using a tutorial, what other errors might there be?